# Which physical qualities have only one unit of measurement?

Tags: units

Are there any physical qualities which have only one unit of measurement?

Comment: What's stopping me from measuring frequency in minute$^{-1}$? Or year$^{-1}$?

Comment: You can also measure frequency in RPM (revolutions per minute), which is 1/60 Hz. I can't think of a single unit you can't express in another form derived from different units. A Watt is a Joule per second, and a Joule is a Watt second.

Comment: For that matter, you could measure frequency in Becquerels too.

Comment: @MarkMitchison & Clara ... I see. Thank you. Hertz is not SI.

Comment: @RandyZeitman 60 Bq is dimensionally equal to 60 Hz, inverse seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 7 SI base units: kilogram, kelvin, second, metre, ampere, mole, candela. Any other derived unit (such as Hertz, or Joule) can also be expressed in terms of SI base units.

I'm not sure if there is an answer to your question, or even if it's a valid question: as long as your physical quantity is related to other physical quantities, it can always be expressed in terms of the units of those other physical quantities (and I think that's always the case).

Comment: Ok, I see... ƒ is not the SI unit, per-second is.